# Dynamically validating a form using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

So I have this project I am working on. I was provided with an HTML file that I CAN NOT edit. I have to access the DOM elements strictly with JavaScipt -- no JQuery, just JavaScript. Right now I am working on the validation. So far when you load the page and click submit the first validation works. However, I also want it to loop through the if statement to validate if the user enters a value in the age input field. I've attached my code below. In the end what I want to happen is when a user enters their age they will be able to add it a list, once the submit button is clicked, that I will need to create dynamically. However, if they don't enter an age or enter in a non-numeric number it will display an error. How can I achieve that?

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";
document.getElementsByTagName('button').onclick = checkAge();

function checkAge() {

  var age = document.getElementsByName['age'];
  if (age == null || age.value === "") {
    alert("Age must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You entered: " + age.value);
    return true;
  }

}
```

```css
.debug {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Household builder</h1>
<div class="builder">
  <ol class="household"></ol>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Age
        <input type="text" name="age">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Relationship
        <select name="rel">
          <option value="">---</option>
          <option value="self">Self</option>
          <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="child">Child</option>
          <option value="parent">Parent</option>
          <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Smoker?
        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add">add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<pre class="debug"></pre>
```

```
Here's my code pen for it too:
```

https://codepen.io/cfay1810/pen/QavNVL

Comment: Code below where?

Comment: _" I've attached my code below"_ um, nope

Comment: I submitted the post before adding the code...oops.

Comment: Maybe the basics first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Comment: Why not use `<input type="number" required min="0" max="120" />`?

Comment: I can't edit the html document...anyway to append that through Javascript?

Comment: What's the difference between the "Add" button and the "Submit" button? Is the intent to add multiple ages to a list before submitting?

Comment: The add button will be used to add additional ages and members to the list after the first submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `onclick` event of the submit button. Instead, use the `onsubmit` event of the form itself. Also don't use the parenthesis when you assign a function to the events. And finally, the `getElementsByTagName` function returns a collection, so you need to select your form. Assuming you only have one form (or your form is the first one on the page):

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";
form.onsubmit = checkAge;
```

Similarly, the first line of your `checkAge` function should be:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
```

Here is the complete code with the fixes:

```js
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "form-handler";
form.onsubmit = checkAge;

function checkAge() {
  var age = document.getElementsByName('age')[0];
  if (age == null || age.value === "") {
    alert("Age must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You entered: " + age.value);
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
.debug {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Household builder</h1>
<div class="builder">
  <ol class="household"></ol>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Age
        <input type="text" name="age">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Relationship
        <select name="rel">
          <option value="">---</option>
          <option value="self">Self</option>
          <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="child">Child</option>
          <option value="parent">Parent</option>
          <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Smoker?
        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add">add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<pre class="debug"></pre>
```

**EDIT** You asked in the comments: **How to add HTML validation attributes to the input box using JavaScript?**. The intended result is something like this:

```
<input type="number" required min="0" max="120" />
```

Note that HTML validation only works in modern browsers. You can easily do that with code like this:

```
var age = document.getElementsByName('age')[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";
```

Here is the complete code with this solution:

```js
var age = document.getElementsByName('age')[0];
age.type = "number";
age.required = true;
age.min = "0";
age.max = "120";
```

```css
.debug {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Household builder</h1>
<div class="builder">
  <ol class="household"></ol>
  <form>
    <div>
      <label>Age
        <input type="text" name="age">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Relationship
        <select name="rel">
          <option value="">---</option>
          <option value="self">Self</option>
          <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
          <option value="child">Child</option>
          <option value="parent">Parent</option>
          <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Smoker?
        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add">add</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="GapViewItemselected">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<pre class="debug"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you, wow I can't believe that was all I was missing! I've been up for days trying to figure it out. I wish I could vote this up, but I just started on here. When I do get my reputation up I'll be sure to come back here. Thanks again!

Comment: You can see my updated answer for an alternative solution to add HTML validation attributes as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, that works great! You have been very helpful today. I can finally move on to the next step.